# Return element containing keyword in Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to get the element that contains my keyword in Jsoup. I have read about how to specify with elements, class and id.

I am wondering how to use a keyword to search a website and return the element containing the keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The selector to use to find an element with a given string (keyword) is `:containsOwn(text)`.

**Example**

```
String html = "<p>Para one</p><p>Para <b>two keyword</b></p>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

Element el = doc.select(":containsOwn(keyword)").first();
Element p = doc.select("p:contains(keyword)").first();

System.out.println(el.html());
System.out.println(p.html());
```

**Output**

```
two keyword
Para <b>two keyword</b>
```

For more details see the [selector cookbook](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) documentation.

The difference between `contains` and `containsOwn` is that the former will include results from child elements.